# Flutter create listview with local sqlite file

Tags: flutter, sqflite

Create a listview from a local sql file(chinook.db) using sqflite
Initial issue solved:
I/flutter ( 5084): Instance of 'Future'
Reference code: https://github.com/tekartik/sqflite/blob/master/sqflite/doc/opening_asset_db.md
Thanks @aakash for the help

```
main.dart
body: Container(
        child: FutureBuilder(
          future: getSQL("albums"),
          builder: (BuildContext context, AsyncSnapshot snapshot) {
            print(snapshot.data);
            if (snapshot.data == null) {
              return Container(child: Center(child: Text("Loading...")));
            } else {
              return ListView.builder(
                itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                itemBuilder: (BuildContext context, int index) {
                  return ListTile(
                    title: Text(snapshot.data[index].title),
                  );
                },
              );
            }
          },
        ),
      ),

getSQL.dart 
Future getSQL(String tableName) async {
  var databasesPath = await getDatabasesPath();
  var path = join(databasesPath, "chinook.db");
// Check if the database exists
  var exists = await databaseExists(path);
  if (!exists) {
    // Should happen only the first time you launch your application
    print("Creating new copy from asset");
    // Make sure the parent directory exists
    try {
      await Directory(dirname(path)).create(recursive: true);
    } catch (_) {}
    // Copy from asset
    ByteData data = await rootBundle.load(join("assets", "chinook.db"));
    List<int> bytes =
        data.buffer.asUint8List(data.offsetInBytes, data.lengthInBytes);
    // Write and flush the bytes written
    await File(path).writeAsBytes(bytes, flush: true);
  } else {
    print("Opening existing database");
  }
// open the database
  var db = await openDatabase(path, readOnly: true);

  List<Map> list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableName');
  List theList = [];
  for (var n in list) {
    theList.add(MyCategoryFinal(n["Title"]));
  }
  return (theList);
}
class MyCategoryFinal {
  final String title;
  MyCategoryFinal(this.title);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I solved this by creating a class for the sqflite table, run a loop on that map list & convert those map items to object list.

Example code;

```
List<ItemBean> items = new List();
    list.forEach((result) {
      ItemBean story = ItemBean.fromJson(result);
      items.add(story);
    });
```

To create the object you can use https://app.quicktype.io/. Here you can pass the json to generate the class for it.

After that you can use FutureBuilder to create your listview like this

```
       FutureBuilder(
          future: MyService.getAllItems(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (!snapshot.hasData) {
              return Center(child: CircularProgressIndicator());
            }

            return ListView.builder(
              controller: listScrollController,
              itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
              reverse: true,
              itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                return Text(snapshot.data[index].itemName);
              },
            );
          },
        ),
```

Comment: Having trouble adding items in class from the orig code, below are added  Future ....List<Map> list = await db.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM $tableName');
  //print(list);

  List<MyCategory> theList = [];
  for (var n in list) {
    MyCategory theList =
        MyCategory(n["CategoryName"], n["CategoryDescription"]);
    theList.add(theList);
  }

  return (theList);
}

class MyCategory {
  final String categoryName;
  final String categoryDescription;
  MyCategory(this.categoryName, this.categoryDescription);
}  Am i doing it wrong?

Comment: You have the same name of list & MyCategory object. Thats why you are facing issue while adding items. When your create `MyCategory theList` within for loop its creating a local object which is replacing the original `theList`. 
Give your object a different name inside for loop or you can simple add the item without creating an object like this
`theList.add(MyCategory(n["CategoryName"], n["CategoryDescription"])); `

Comment: Thanks @aakash, solved the issue. Edited orig post for reference